# iOS pod install thorws error RPC failed; curl 26 .netrc parser error fatal: expected flush after ref listing

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods

I am running a `pod install` on my ios project but it failing with below error

RPC failed; curl 26 .netrc parser error
fatal: expected flush after ref listing

and it is happening for 3rd party libraries like `lottie-ios`

Comment: Maybe it is a poor internet connection.  Can you try it at another time, or from a different location to see if it helps?

Comment: @FaisalMemon its been happening since Yesterday so I am pretty sure its not related to the internet or location

Comment: OK, try `pod install --verbose` and share the output.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new line to the end of ~/.netrc file resolved the issue for me